# Scala type check complaining with lambda, not with explicit Function

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala code:

```scala
import java.util.{Comparator, function}

object ComparatorTest {
  Comparator.comparing[Int, String](new function.Function[Int, String] {
    override def apply(t: Int): String = t.toString
  })
}
```

which compiles without issue. I think I should be able to replace that `Function` with a lambda ([that's what I understand from the doc, at least](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types), and IntelliJ is of the same opinion). However, when I replace it with

```scala
  Comparator.comparing[Int, String]((t: Int) ⇒ t.toString)
```

I get a compiler error:

```
Error:(6, 23) overloaded method value comparing with alternatives:
  (x$1: java.util.function.Function[_ >: Int, _ <: String])java.util.Comparator[Int] <and>
  (x$1: java.util.function.Function[_ >: Int, _ <: String],x$2: java.util.Comparator[_ >: String])java.util.Comparator[Int]
 cannot be applied to (Int => String)
  Comparator.comparing[Int, String]((t: Int) ⇒ t.toString)
```

(It looks to me like the first alternative should match.)

[I've just asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54609769/scala-resolving-to-wrong-override-in-comparator-thencomparing/54610279#54610279), and the solution was to explicitly specify type parameters, but in this case, I think I've specified everything I could. Is there another solution to use a lambda, or is an explicit `Function` needed here? If the latter, is there a doc that explains when exactly a lambda can be substituted for a SAM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: Use [`Ordering`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/math/Ordering.html) rather than using `Comparator` directly.

---

You can use type ascription to force it to recognize your argument as a `java.util.function.Function[Int, String]`:

```
Comparator.comparing[Int, String]((_.toString) : function.Function[Int, String])
```

Note that the parentheses around `_.toString` are required; otherwise, it tries to apply the ascription to the expression in the lambda rather than the lambda as a whole. This code is basically equivalent to:

```
val tmp: function.Function[Int, String] = _.toString
Comparator.comparing[Int, String](tmp)
```

---

However, when writing Scala, is generally better to use `Ordering`. Since `Ordering` extends `Comparator`, it can be used anywhere a `Comparator` is expected. You could use it like:

```
val cmp: Comparator[Int] = Ordering.by(_.toString)
```

or:

```
val cmp = Ordering.by[Int, String](_.toString)
```

As you can see, the type inference works far better here.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the reason I sometimes use `Comparators` is because they have the `thenCompare` method which I find useful for building them and doesn't play nice with `Orderings`. [Scala 2.13 will have it for Orderings](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5988), but who knows when it'll be out :p

Comment: @zale In the meantime, you can use tuples to build Orderings like that, e.g. `Ordering.by(user => (user.lastName, user.firstName))` for `Ordering.by(_.lastName).orElseBy(_.firstName)` (though I admit it's less readable).

Answer (score 1):

If the reason for using `Comparator` instead of `Ordering` is `thenCompare`, that is easily overcome with an implicit:

```
object PimpOrdering {
  implicit class OrderOrElse[T](val o: Ordering[T]) extends AnyVal {
   def orElse(o2: Ordering[T]) = new Ordering[T] {
     def compare(a: T, b: T) = {
        val cmp = o.compare(a,b)
        if (cmp == 0) o2.compare(a,b) else cmp
     }
   }
   def orElse[S : Ordering](f: T => S) = orElse(Ordering.by(f))
 }
}
```

Now you can write things like

```
Ordering.by[Foo, String](_.foo).orElse(_.bar).orElse(_.baz)
```

etc